# Gson can't deserialize multiple type List

Tags: java, android, serialization, gson

I have a class which holds other objects in an `ArrayList`:

```
class Program {
    @Expose
    private List<BaseData> dataList;
}
```

And I have other classes:

```
class BaseData {
    @Expose
    String name;
}

class Data extends BaseData {
    @Expose
    String description;
}

class DataA extends Data{
    @Expose
    String a;
}

class DataB extends Data{
    @Expose
    String b;
}
```

When I would like to serialize it:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
Log.d(TAG, gson.toJson(myProgram));
```

I can see only the keys which I have in `BaseData`. My list in my `Program` object contains `DataA`, `DataB` and `Data` objects too.

How can I fix this?

**Update:**

So my program work like this: it does stuff and fills the `Program`'s list with data. Than I save it: I use `Gson` to turn the `Program` to a json string. I use `Shared Preferences`.
Than when I open up the app again, it loads the previously saved json string. I `Log.d` it, and everything is cool.

**Than**

I would like to create a Program object from that json.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
instance = gson.fromJson(savedJson, Program.class);
```

And after I serialize it again with `Gson` happens what I wrote above. So it seems that it only creates `BaseData` objects from the json.

Comment: I bet you don't have `Data.description`, `DataA.a` and `DataB.b` initialized and all of them are `null`. It must be working at least for Gson 2.8.0.

Comment: You lost a bet than. They are not null, I checked them already.

Comment: Can you provide the initialization code and the version of Gson you're using? `gson.toJson(new Program(asList(new DataA("foo", "bar", "baz"), new DataB("foo", "bar", "baz"))))` produces the following JSON: `{"dataList":[{"a":"baz","description":"bar","name":"foo"},{"b":"baz","description":"bar","name":"foo"}]}`

Comment: Also, try to add `serializeNulls()` to the `GsonBuilder` instance hopefully to make sure what really is happening to your result JSON.

Comment: I tried to add `serializeNulls()` but nothing changes

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv I updated my question. It turns out that the problem is with the object creation from the json string.

Comment: Mate, then I didn't lose the bet. ;) If you're going to deserialize `DataA` and `DataB`, then you must tell Gson how they can be generated and where from. `BaseData` is just `BaseData`, and nothing helps Gson to figure out that it can be one of `BaseDate` subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

I found the **Solution**.

Btw. It feels like a bit "brute force" method.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JSONObject progJsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
progJsonObj.clearDataList();
JSONArray dataList= reader.getJSONArray("dataList");
Program program = gson.fromJson(progJsonObj.toString());
for (int i = 0; i < dataList.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject blockData = blocksInProgram.getJSONObject(i);
    // Added new class variable of the base class
    String type = blockData.getString("dataType");
    if (type.equals("data_a")) {
        DataA d = gson.fromJson(blockData.toString(), DataA.class);
        program.addData(d);
    } else if (type.equals("data_b")){
        DataB d = gson.fromJson(blockData.toString(), DataB.class);
        program.addData(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're resolving a trivial deserialization issue, and Gson has an extra for exactly the same purpose: take a look at https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java -- see the javadocs how the data types can be resolved for you. Also, apart of that, please note that `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` come from `org.json` and may not work with Gson for other cases (you might be confused with `JsonObject` and `JsonArray` that are provided by Gson).

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv Thanks! I found that class but it was too late... Thanks for the help again!